# Codeigniter image manipulation text watermark line breaks

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to put a multiline watermark on images using CodeIgniters Image Manipulation library, but I can't get it to work.

I'm setting the text with

```
$config['source_image']= $newFile;
$str = '';
$str.='Px: ';
$str .= $config['width'];
$str .= "\r\n";
$str.=' | Qual: '.$config['quality'];
$str .= "\n";
$str.=' Size: '.$size;
$str .= "<br />";
$str.=' File: '.$fileName;  
$config['wm_text'] = $str;
```

etc

There's no mention of it in the documentation and I can't see anything about it on here or Google.  It's not important - it's only a personal project, but I'd like to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the Image_lib.php class in system/libraries, you'll find it uses the [imagettftext](http://php.net/imagettftext) function:

```
imagettftext($src_img, $this->wm_font_size, 0, $x_shad, $y_shad, $drp_color, $this->wm_font_path, $this->wm_text);
```

The `$y_shad`variable determines the vertical offset of the entire text provided. If you want linebreaks, you'd have to have your text variable be an array, then use a foreach loop to increase the vertical offset for each line (that is, each item in the array).

To achieve this however, you'd have to drastically alter the `text_watermark`method inside CI's Image_lib.php class, since you'd now be dealing with the text variable as an array, instead of a simple string. So it's not impossible but rather tedious to achieve, and therefor most likely not worth the effort...

Comment: Thanks @Mudshark.  You're right, it would be far too much work just to note a few stats about each image.  I'm trying lots of combinations or original filesize and resolutions with lots of different CI settings to find the sweet spot for my adaptive/responsive images

Answer (score 1):

```
function imagettfmultilinetext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $fontfile,  $text, $spacing=1)
{
    $lines=explode("\n",$text);
    for($i=0; $i< count($lines); $i++)
    {
        $newY=$y+($i * $size * $spacing);
        imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $newY, $color, $fontfile,  $lines[$i], $spacing);
    }
    return null;
}
```